# Text is not selected from drop down list in autoit

Tags: autoit

From outlook plugin i am trying to fetch the text from drop down .

I have the following code.

```
#Include <GuiComboBox.au3>
#Include <GuiComboBoxEX.au3>
#include <GUIListBox.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiButton.au3>

global $hcombo = "[NAME:cboMeetingRooms]"
global $hcomboclass = "[CLASS:WindowsForms10.COMBOBOX.app.0.2d538d3_r86_ad4]"
global $title = "Lifesize Cloud Outlook Add-In Settings"
global $index = 0
local $sText = 'headset'

WinActivate($title)

sleep(3000)

local $shcombo = ControlGetHandle($title, "", $hcombo)
$Index = _GUICtrlComboBox_FindStringExact($shcombo, $sText)
ConsoleWrite($Index)
$tt = _GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($shcombo, $Index)
ConsoleWrite($tt)
sleep(3000)
```

Plz Plz Plz help me out to get the selected string . I am getting the Correct index  but the text in not been selected![enter image description here][1]

I have gone through all the code :( but didnot find the result

Output:

```
   >"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE\..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut 
    "C:\Users\mm1\Desktop\AutoIT\ex.au3"    
8-1>Exit code: 0    Time: 7.195
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at how I set the selection with SetCurSel and then read the combo for the selected item.

```
#Include <GuiComboBox.au3>
#Include <GuiComboBoxEX.au3>
#include <GUIListBox.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiButton.au3>

global $hcombo = "[NAME:cboMeetingRooms]"
global $hcomboclass = "[CLASS:WindowsForms10.COMBOBOX.app.0.2d538d3_r86_ad4]"
global $title = "Lifesize Cloud Outlook Add-In Settings"
global $index = 0
local $sText = 'headset'

WinActivate($title)

sleep(3000)

local $shcombo = ControlGetHandle($title, "", $hcombo)
$Index = _GUICtrlComboBox_FindStringExact($shcombo, $sText)
ConsoleWrite($Index)
_GUICtrlComboBox_SetCurSel($shcombo, $Index)
$tt = GUICtrlRead($shcombo) ; this will give you the value that we set selected /w SetCurSel
ConsoleWrite($tt)
sleep(3000)
```

Comment: Please, mark it as solved so others can see it worked. My pleasure :D

Comment: Hi,  how can i select the item from the drop down when there is no combo box name . see the below command . Plz help me out how to select an item when combo name is not fetched from AutoIT v3 Window Info

Comment: >>>> Window <<<<
Title: Outlook Add-In Settings
Class: HwndWrapper[Lifesize.Cloud.Outlook.AddIn.vsto|vstolocal;;691f4ce3-1eea-434d-aa29-1ec27efe5c24]
Position: 433, 214
Size: 500, 300
Style: 0x16C00000
ExStyle: 0x00040100
Handle: 0x00000000001C0044
>>>> Control <<<<
Class: 
Instance: 
ClassnameNN: 
Name: 
Advanced (Class): 
ID: 
Text: 
Position: 
Size: 
ControlClick Coords: 
Style: 
ExStyle: 
Handle: 
>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position: 866, 263
Cursor ID: 0
Color: 0xDADADA
>>>> StatusBar <<<<
>>>> ToolsBar <<<<
>>>> Visible Text <<<<
>>>> Hidden Text <<<<

Comment: It looks like the ID of the control is 0, try and use that with ControlGetHandle, to see if you can get the handle to the control.

Comment: Hi Hargrove ,    I tried the below command "ControlGetHandle" , failed to fetch the string from drop down . Could you plz tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: `Local $hControl = ControlGetHandle("Outlook Add-In", "", "")         
$findstring = _GUICtrlComboBox_FindStringExact($hControl, "align")  
_GUICtrlComboBox_SetCurSel($hControl, $findstring)  
$setvalue = GUICtrlRead($hControl)`

Comment: Have you tried instead of the title the Class, ClassNN, or the ID?

Comment: ClassNN and ID both are empty .  Please see the below code of control .   `>>>> Control <<<< 
Class: 
Instance:
ClassnameNN:
Name: 
Advanced (Class): 
ID: 
Text: 
Position: 
Size: 
ControlClick Coords: 
Style: 
ExStyle: 
Handle: `

Comment: `>>> Window <<<< Title: 
Outlook Add-In Settings Class: HwndWrapper[.AddIn.vsto|vstolocal;;691f4ce3-1eea-43‌​4d-aa29-1ec27efe5c24] Position: 433, 214 Size: 500, 300 Style: 0x16C00000 ExStyle: 0x00040100 Handle: 0x00000000001C0044 `